How to catch or log SEH exceptions in .NET 6 or later?
In .NET 4.8 SEH exceptions ("Structured Exception Handling") could be caused by specifying the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute. In later .NET versions the attribute is not available, and a SEH exception will cause the application to crash without any information about stack trace etc.
How to get the stack trace to solve issues in the code?
Tried to add the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute, but no effect in .NET 6.

Accordingly to documentation, you need to apply one more attribute SecurityCritical to make it work:
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions, SecurityCritical]
public void CriticalExcptionHandler()
{
    // here you will be able to handle the exception
}

From linked docs:

The CLR delivers the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses only in methods that have both the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute and SecurityCriticalAttribute attributes.


The HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute is unfortunately marked as obsolete in .NET 6.

@Coragi Yes, that means that MS discourages using it and you should stop using it. If needed, you always can try to fork the implementation from the original source.
